# How to change migration db connection

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have more than one connection setting in `config/database.php`, I can and have to connect to several database in the same case, this is how I try to do but not work.

```
<?php

class Migration_Create_loggers_table extends CI_Migration
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('master');
    }

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field([
            'id' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 50
            ]
        ]);

        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', true);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('members');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('members');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but I think you are missing `parent::__construct();` at your `__construct` method

So your `__construct` method should be like this

```
class Migration_Create_loggers_table extends CI_Migration
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database('master');
        parent::__construct();//add this line
    }

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field([
            'id' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 50
            ]
        ]);

        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', true);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('members');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('members');
    }
}
```